# Is this interference or superimposed image?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, optics

When you overlay two identical screens a new patterns forms as they offset. See image:
The two screens are not touching or interacting with each other.
Are the different patterns we see as the two screens shift considered interference or just superimposed images?
Like combining shades and colors in a painting, Is the finished product considered interference or super imposed image?
[image: One screen on top of another]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern

Comment: Moire patterns are not interference patterns in the sense that the word "interference" is used in wave optics.  However, Moire patterns are closely analogous to interference patterns.

Comment: @S.McGrew how would you best describe the difference between Moire patterns and interference used in optics? Thanks

Comment: The answer by @nielsnielsen is a simple and correct description of the difference.

Answer (score 3):

this is a superposition of two images. it is not interference in the *optical* sense because the light from the two images is not cancelling out in certain zones due to wave interactions.

Answer (score 1):

A **linear superposition** is a weighted sum of some quantities $E_i$ for $i=1,2, \ldots, n$
$$
E_{tot} = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i E_i = c_1 E_1 + c_2 E_2 + \ldots + c_n E_n
$$
Instead, the term **interference** is in *my opinion* strongly linked with the square of such a linear superposition, e.g. in optics the intensity,
$$
I_{tot} \propto |E_{tot}|^2 = \left|\sum_{i=1}^n c_i E_i \right|^2
$$
or in quantum mechanics
$$
|\Psi_{tot}|^2 =  \left|\sum_{i=1}^n c_i \psi_i \right|^2
$$
Maybe there are other examples which uses higher powers, but they probably all involve a cross-term/mix-term/interaction term $E_1 E_2$. Thus, in my opinion the images shows a superposition of two images, and *not* an interference.